# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 Minimal on an Intel Atom D2500HN based system

Tags: 13.04, boot, intel

I'm trying to install Ubuntu `13.04` Minimal on a new Intel Atom D2500HN based system.
The full desktop install runs absolutely fine (but cripplingly slow) and I can get Lubuntu running from the CD without issue as well (though I haven't tried installing it).

The minimal installer appears to complete without issue, but when it comes to boot I just get a blank screen.

I think it's having trouble displaying the text mode screen (I've tried switching to an alternate TTY using the Lubuntu demo and that seems to hang, however I don't know if the basic Lubuntu setup would have left the other TTY's enabled).

Does anyone have any advice on how I can get this to start properly?

**EDIT**

It's also worth noting that having re-installed with `SSH` I can access the system fine, so everything else is obviously running fine.

Comment: How is your display (which type) connected?

Comment: It's an onboard VGA connection.

Comment: And the monitor went not in standby? Maybe you have to center the image?

Comment: It's not in standby but it does appear to think that there's no signal in those modes.  (I've tried a different monitor as well)

Answer (score 0):

It could be 2 things:

- brightness: try using:

  ```
  i915.invert_brightness=1
  ```

  as kernel boot parameter,
- If you have dual graphics, perhaps you need to blacklist the module. This happened to me in my Intel + Ati configuration.